# Default Indentations for Word Headings

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, microsoft-office-2010

I've created several dot and dotm templates for company documents, with multilevel headings 1 through 10 flush with the left margin, and 18 points above and below, but the definitions for headings seem to take on a life of their own, reverting to an ominous .38 indentation for Heading 1 and 3.18 indentation for a Heading 4, with 6 pts above/below.

I've expunged every source for this (setting my own local Normal.dot, locking (password protecting) the network dotm, even cleanup of docs ready for publication. Some user always comes back with the .38 indent problem.

The immediate solution was to have that person copy the Heading 1 into their local normal.dot.

This oddity is very persistent, but not documented anywhere in Microsoft resources. Any input from superusers?

Comment: Please check whether you have checked the box of Automatically updating. If you use the Office 365, you could right click the Heading 1 in Styles box, choose Modify and uncheck the box of Automatically updating.
Maybe you could refer to the article "How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in your Microsoft Word document" on the following page of the Late Shauna Kelly's website: [create numbered headings or outline numbering](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft MVP [mjcatt_086](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/attaching-document-template-results-in-heading/bd09122b-b9b7-4e0b-b37e-7b99b8743545) has an answer--two parts, actually, using Shauna Kelly's detailed instructions from 2007, with a clarifying limitation that Modify Style does not apply to multilevel heading styles; these MUST be created/defined by selecting Define New Multilevel List.

A new list, starting with heading 1 and manually walking through the exhaustive dialog selections IN ORDER from level 1 to level 9, adding a previous level AND setting a number, the font, and text color for each heading.

You can't change the numbering, but you can update the definition to refine the hanging indent, tab, and vertical spacing from within a document. (I think the OLD multilevel heading definition was overwriting my heading styles--for the past year!!!!)

An ADDITIONAL caveat is how you attach style definitions to a document, which occurs about 4/5ths the way down that post:

What I have discovered is there must be a bug in the template attachment process.  Here is what I have to do to get it to work correctly in Word 2016:

1. Open the "Templates and add-ins" dialog, attach my template, CHECK
   the "Automatically update document styles", close the dialog.
2. Reopen the "Templates and add-ins" dialog, UNCHECK the
   "Automatically update document styles", close the dialog.

   3. Reopen the "Templates and add-ins" dialog, CHECK the "Automatically
      update document styles", close the dialog.

After step 1 nothing apparently happens since "Automatically update..." is not checked.
After step 2 the styles pane shows all the headings styles with multilevel list attributes.
After step 3 the styles pane shows exactly as it should for my attached template (no multilevel list attributes on the heading styles) and everything is good to go!!!